# Where is Electron's internal webContents defined?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to understand how Electron loads extensions. In tracing the code, I'm getting stuck [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/bb2ab01f99fb790f0d271211c1c3572ed4511e02/lib/browser/chrome-extension.js#L98):

`const contents = webContents.create({`

within:

```
const { app, webContents, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const startBackgroundPages = function (manifest) {
  if (backgroundPages[manifest.extensionId] || !manifest.background) return

  let html
  let name
  if (manifest.background.page) {
    name = manifest.background.page
    html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(manifest.srcDirectory, manifest.background.page))
  } else {
    name = '_generated_background_page.html'
    const scripts = manifest.background.scripts.map((name) => {
      return `<script src="${name}"></script>`
    }).join('')
    html = Buffer.from(`<html><body>${scripts}</body></html>`)
  }

  const contents = webContents.create({
    partition: 'persist:__chrome_extension',
    type: 'backgroundPage',
    sandbox: true,
    enableRemoteModule: false
  })
  backgroundPages[manifest.extensionId] = { html: html, webContents: contents, name: name }
  contents.loadURL(url.format({
    protocol: 'chrome-extension',
    slashes: true,
    hostname: manifest.extensionId,
    pathname: name
  }))
}
```

I'd like to just follow the `require`, but I'm not finding success in that. It's also very unclear to me where/how the contents of the module get populated, so that's styming my attempts to trace it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Majority of electron's code is native codes to create binding to chromium and webcontents is also same. Specifically webcobtents.create is defined here https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/49b47ee4edb6e90545ca56ed2d3c051437df9521/shell/browser/api/atom_api_web_contents.h#L95

Reason you cannot see how it's constructed is since this is native bindings you are not easily able to peek context in your javascript context.

Comment: Fantastic, super helpful!

Comment: Do you have any idea where the `webContents` instance that's pulled in by the `require` is defined?

Comment: same as above code: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/49b47ee4edb6e90545ca56ed2d3c051437df9521/shell/browser/api/atom_api_web_contents.cc#L2662 there's no javascript involved.